# Notepad++ messed up my numbers

Tags: notepad++, fonts

[image: Display of the problem]

How do I fix the problem where Notepadd++ doesn't show numbers like usual

Comment: When you go to `Encoding` what is this doc where the numbers are not showing encoded in exactly? It should also show in the lower right hand side of the NP++ window. Maybe try converting a copy of the file to another encoding format to test in case for some reason NP++ isn't detecting what to open it with encoding wise (UNICODE maybe?). You might also try to upgrade your NP++ version if you're on an older version potentially as well.

Comment: I dunno. I think having the number `3` be an `airplane` symbol might be an improvement to some of my code :)

Comment: Change every encoding before. Still no result

Comment: Use menu *Settings* > *Style Configurator* and in *Select theme* dropdown keep pressing down arrow key and observe how styles are changing. Are your numbers messed up in every single theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just damaged the font somehow.
You can spot the pattern:

- 0 → grid
- 3 → airplane
- 5 → empty
- 6 → grid
- 7 → airplane
- 8 → empty

If you can provide more information, perhaps more specific help can be possible.
Also please see my [tip](https://superuser.com/questions/1097848/notepad-messed-up-my-numbers/1098188#comment1557892_1097848).

Comment: I found the issue there. Changed to Consolas and now it works fine.